# How to check which currency conversions that spotlight supports? Is the currency supported by different regions different?

Tags: spotlight

How to check which currency conversions that spotlight supports? Is the currency supported by different regions different? Currently, I set the area to Hong Kong, supporting most currencies including HKD TWD RMB EUR USD SGD. But does not support Turkish lira(TRY) and Vietnam Dong(VND).

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight uses the Calculator App to convert the currency. You can check the supports currency in Calculator——convert——currency.
Because the data source comes from Yahoo, I think that as long as I can access Yahoo, it should be the same. I tried China, Hong Kong, Taiwan, and the United States. There is no difference.